# Having trouble reading in content of url using InputStream

Tags: java, io, inputstream, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

So I run the code below and it prints "!DOCTYPE html". How do I get the content of the url, like the html for instance?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL u = new URL("https://www.whitehouse.gov/");
        InputStream ins = u.openStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader websiteText = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println(websiteText.readLine());

    }
```

According to java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html: "When you run the program, you should see, scrolling by in your command window, the HTML commands and textual content from the HTML file located at ".... Why am I not getting that?

Comment: The code you posted isn't the same as the code from the tutorial you cited, so there is no reason why it should behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, **your did not put while loop**.

```
   URL u = new URL("https://www.whitehouse.gov/");
    InputStream ins = u.openStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader websiteText = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = websiteText.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(inputLine);
   }

  websiteText.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading one line of the text. 
Try this and you will see that you get two lines:

```
System.out.println(websiteText.readLine());
System.out.println(websiteText.readLine());
```

Try reading it in a loop to get all the text.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader has a method called #lines() since Java 8. The return type of #lines() is Stream. To read an entire site you could do something like that:

```
String htmlText = websiteText.lines()
  .reduce("", (text, nextLine) -> text + "\n" + nextLine)
  .orElse(null);
```